# Jquery Checkbox change event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Am trying to sortout this small issue from past hour :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("input[name='isClubMember']:checkbox").mousedown(function() {
         if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            this.checked = confirm("Are you sure?");
            $(this).trigger("change");
         }
    });
 });
</script>
```

Funnily this works in JSFiddle ..but not in my jsp page.
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/JXbYt/)

The above code gives me `null` error at this line (in Debug console)

```
 $("input[name='isClubMember']:checkbox").mousedown(function() {
```

JQ -Ver : 1.7.2 Browser : IE8

**Update** :
   Error in IE console :

```
 'null' is null or not an object
```

at the above mentioned line

Comment: Why not `change` instead of `mousedown`

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you receive? Even if the selector doesn't match anything, `mousedown()` should still be safe to call.

Comment: @AlexBall : Even `change` is the same ..no luck

Comment: change name='isClubMember' to name=isClubMember

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : Have updated my qn with error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *looks* like your JSP page includes the [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library after jQuery.

Prototype's [$()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/) function takes an id and returns `null` if it cannot find the element, which is consistent with the behavior you're observing.

Try using `jQuery` instead of `$` everywhere in your code:

```
jQuery("input[name='isClubMember']:checkbox").mousedown(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Or put your code in a closure that is passed the `jQuery` object in a `$` argument:

```
(function($) {
    // The rest of your code...
})(jQuery);
```

Or take advantage of the fact that a `ready` handler is passed the same `$` argument:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // The code in your 'ready' handler...
});
```

You may also want to run jQuery in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode, to avoid overriding Prototype's `$()` function if the order of inclusion changes.

Comment: Hamidi : +1 Excellent.. Yes I am using `Prototype` with `scriptaculous`.. How do I overcome this one ? Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest, you could add a class name to the checkbox, and find the checkbox by a class name! it seems thats the problem with ie8 in this case!

Answer (score 0):

*I think in your page jQuery is not connected. Check.*

I think so because $ - function and returns object anyway, but if there is no jQuery then $(str) returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the selector is broken in IE8 somehow, try [type='checkbox'], should be faster anyway

```
    $("input[name='isClubMember'][type='checkbox']").mousedown(function() {
```